# Uncheck a checkbox when it is ng-disabled AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, dropdown, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have this dropdown with three roles:

1. Super Admin
2. Admin
3. User

And this checkbox that sets some extra privileges

- Give extra privileges.

What I want to achieve is this:
When the User role is selected in the dropdown, the checkbox is BOTH disabled and unchecked. I have managed to disable it but if it has been checked beforehand, then it remains checked when disabled.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.model = {
    role: '',
    roles: ['Super Admin', 'Admin', 'User'],
    givePrivileges: false
}
```

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Role</label>
    <md-select ng-model="model.role">
        <md-option ng-repeat="role in model.roles" ng-value="role">
            {{role}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container>
    <md-checkbox ng-disabled="model.role === 'User'">
        Give extra privileges
    </md-checkbox>
</md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assign ng-model:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="model.givePrivileges" ng-disabled="model.role === 'User'">
    Give extra privileges
</md-checkbox>
```

Then handle dropdown change:

```
<md-select ng-model="model.role" ng-change="handleRoleChange()">
    <md-option ng-repeat="role in model.roles" ng-value="role">
        {{role}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.handleRoleChange = function () {
    if ($scope.model.role === 'User') {
        $scope.model.givePrivileges = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing an ng-model on your md-checkbox. You can bind givePrivileges variable with the md-checkbox. Then you can write a watch statement on the value of role. and update the givePrivileges variable as needed.

HTML

```
 <md-checkbox ng-modal="modal.givePrivileges" ng-disabled="model.role === 'User'">
        Give extra privileges
 </md-checkbox>
```

JS

```
$scope.$watch('model.role', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
        if (newVal === ''User) {
            $scope.model.givePrivileges = false;
        }
    }
});
```